# What is the long fork tool the maesters hold in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I see the maesters holding a long metal stick or fork they use to examine people. What is that, what is it used for and why?

Comment: Are you referring to the final inspection of Jorah Mormont? If so, Jorah had greyscale. It's supposed to be mortal and contagious. The Maesters would obviously refrain from touching him with their own hands.

Comment: @Möoz It appears that someone edited this from maesters to masters and so changed the question. I've edited it back to say maesters.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** It's just an inspection tool used so the examiner doesn't have to touch the patient so they don't contract the disease themselves, in this case it is greyscale which is passed on by touch and highly contagious.

---

It would appear you are referring to this tool that we see Archmaester Ebrose use first when he does an initial inspection of Jorah's greyscale and later on after Sam has healed him.

[image: Ebrose inspects Jorah's greyscale]
<sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 2, "Stormborn" - Ebrose inspects Jorah's greyscale.</sub>

[image: Ebrose inspects Jorah's healed skin for any signs of greyscale]
<sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 3, "The Queen's Justice" - Ebrose inspects Jorah's healed skin for any signs of greyscale. Close up of the inspection tool used.</sub>

Put bluntly the tool is simply just a metal stick with a pointy end; a medical tool used to examine patients so that the maester doesn't have to touch them. Why wouldn't they touch them? Well as I'm sure you remember greyscale is incredibly infectious and once someone has contracted they are almost certain to die from it, in fact Jorah contracted it himself from a touch from one of the Stone Men.

> **Priestess:** *(Valyrian)* The Lord of Light hears your voice. He hears the king as he hears the slave; he hears the Stone Men in their misery...
>
> **Tyrion:** Stone men. Good luck stopping this spread of grayscale with prayer. You'd have better luck dancing away the plague.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 5 Episode 3, "High Sparrow"</sub>

> *ARCHMAESTER EBROSE, SAMWELL and JORAH are standing together in the quarantine room. JORAH's upper body is covered in Greyscale except his face.*
>
> **Ebrose:** The infection has spread too far. You should have cut off your arm the moment you were touched.
>
> **Jorah:** How long?
>
> **Ebrose:** It will be years before it kills you. It could be 10, could be 20.
>
> **Jorah:** But how long 'till...
>
> **Ebrose:** Your mind? Six months, maybe fewer.
>
> *JORAH sighs and sits down on his bed. SAMWELL approaches EBROSE.*
>
> **Sam:** Pardon, Archmaester. I met Stannis Baratheon's daughter at Castle Black. She had Greyscale as a baby and was cured. Isn't there some way --
>
> **Ebrose:** Does this look like a baby to you?
>
> **Sam:** No.
>
> **Ebrose:** Have you studied the varying rates of Greyscale progression in infants and fully grown men?
>
> **Sam:** No.
>
> **Ebrose:** Maester Chrissen discovered Shireen Baratheon's affliction immediately.
>
> *EBROSE turns to face JORAH.*
>
> **Ebrose:** This is quite advanced and beyond our skills, Ser.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 2, "Stormborn"</sub>

> **Jorah:** I surrendered to this sickness the moment I first saw it. I knew it would kill me or I'd kill myself before it could. Daenerys Stormborn convinced me otherwise. The only place for me is with her.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 3, "The Queen's Justice"</sub>

In fact there have only been 2 recorded cases of advanced greyscale being cured, with other examples of earlier forms being cured such as Shireen Baratheon's.

> **Stannis:** When you were an infant, the Dornish trailer landed on Dragonstone. His goods were junk except for one wooden doll. He'd even sewn a dress on it in the colors of our House. No doubt he'd heard of your birth, and assumed new fathers were easy targets. I still remember how you smiled when I put that doll in your cradle, and you pressed it to your cheek. By the time we burnt the doll, it was too late. I was told you would die. Or worse, the grayscale would go slow.Let you grow just enough to know the world before taking it away from you. Everyone advised me to send you to the ruins of Valyria to live out your short life with the Stone men, before the sickness spread to the castle. I told them all to go to hell. I called in every maester on this side of the world. Every healer, every apothecary. They stopped the disease and saved your life. Because you did not belong across the world with the bloody Stone men. You are the Princess Shireen of House Baratheon. And you are my daughter.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 5 Episode 4, "Sons of the Harpy"</sub>

> **Sam:** I may have found a way to treat Ser Jorah. There are two recorded cases of advanced Greyscale being cured. I found the procedure in the Study of Rare Diseases by Archmaester Pilos.
>
> *EBROSE places a book on SAMWELL's stack. He continues looking at more books.*
>
> **Ebrose:** I'm familiar with Archmaester Pylos and the Study of Rare Diseases.
>
> **Sam:** Oh, you are?
>
> **Ebrose:** Yes. Should I tell you how he died? From Greyscale.
>
> *EBROSE places another book on SAMWELL's stack.*
>
> **Sam:** Oh.
>
> **Ebrose:** The procedure is far too dangerous which is why it's now forbidden.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 2, "Stormborn"</sub>

Comment: A lot of the information in this answer seems superfluous. Do you need to go into so much detail about the infectiousness and history of greyscale, rather than simply answering the question of what the tool is and leaving it at that?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Do I need to go into as much detail as I do? Probably not, however, the question does state _"why"_ which means some detail is needed. I could probably cut some of it but I feel like each part adds enough extra information that it is worthwhile keeping. The TL:DR is there for those who don't want to read on.

Comment: Interesting for those of us that haven't seen Game of Thrones :)